# Write a Special Character in Rs232 connection in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, special-characters

I need send some special characters in a rs232 connection, but I'm with troubles.

For example, when I want send the character ¿ I write:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream.write("\u00BF".getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```

The receiver receive two characteres (Â¿) and I don't know why.
When I send normal characteres all runs well.

Anyone have any idea of what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What is receiving? Hardware, third party software or your software? Does it work OK for standard alphabet?

Comment: Or skip the whole string and write the bytes out as you already know the code `outputStream.write(0xbf);`

Comment: Receiver is one terminal in other pc. Yes, it work ok for standard alphabet.

Comment: You're sending a two-byte Unicode character, and you say the receiving end regards it as two characters.  I suspect something along the way regards these as 8-bit characters, possibly ASCII, possibly even 7-bit characters.  I don't know how the character 00 would be rendered in ASCII, or on your system, but it might be worth looking into.  Try sending 0x3132 and see if you get the characters '1' and '2'.

Comment: When I send 0x3132 only receive the character '2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I detect that in zero position of "\u00BF".getBytes() has the character Â.
Why? I have no idea!

So, I write only the first position:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream.write("\u00BF".getBytes()[1]);
outputStream.flush();
```

This only happens in the special characters, in the normal I can write the zero position.
Thanks!